# WebSockets in Python3.1 handshake problem

Tags: html, websocket

i am using python3.1 ,so i found a html5 websocket snippet here:

http://www.nublue.co.uk/blog/threaded-python-websocket-server-and-javascript-client/

I test with chrome.

After send handshake packet,web client  has no response as expect(websocket.onopen is not fired).I do receive client's request.
.i tried many times.It just not work.

---

Here is a .NET code:

http://nugget.codeplex.com/

I test it,it works fine.so my chrome is ok. 
I wanna know is there any python3.x  demo code can give me a help.

And my machine:
WIN7 pro X86

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [noVNC](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC) project (a HTML5 VNC client) contains a python 2.X (but should be easy to convert to 3.X) utility named [wsproxy](http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC/tree/master/utils/) which is a WebSockets to generic TCP proxy. It transparently supports v75 and v76 (which has new handshake) of the WebSockets protocol.

If you're still working on it, that might be a helpful reference at least.

Disclaimer: I made noVNC and wsproxy.

Comment: i'd appreciate a win32-compatible version (without `fork()`)

Comment: This is websockify [Issue #2](https://github.com/kanaka/websockify/issues/2). Good patches accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

oh.i got it .

that article is obsolete.

and see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Sockets

sum of the concatenated string.[1]

sum of the concatenated string.[1]> The Sec-WebSocket-Key1 and

> Sec-WebSocket-Key2 fields and the 8
>   bytes after the fields are random
>   tokens which the server uses to
>   construct a 16-byte token at the end
>   of its handshake to prove that it has
>   read the client's handshake. The
>   handshake is constructed by
>   concatenating the numbers from the
>   first key, and dividing by the number
>   of spaces. This is then repeated for
>   the second key. The two resulting
>   numbers are concatenated with each
>   other, and with the last 8 bytes after
>   the fields. The final result is an MD5
>   sum of the concatenated string.[1]sum of the concatenated string.[1]

sum of the concatenated string.[1]