# Bytes and integers and concatenation and python

Tags: python, byte, md5

I have 2 32bit unsigned integers..

777007543
and
114997259

and the string of bytes..

0x47 0x30 0x22 0x2D 0x5A 0x3F 0x47 0x58

How do I get python to give me the concatenation of these 3 such that I have...

0x2E 0x50 0x31 0xB7 0x06 0xDA 0xB8 0x0B 0x47 0x30 0x22 0x2D 0x5A 0x3F 0x47 0x58

I would then run that through an md5 hash and get...

0x30 0x73 0x74 0x33 0x52 0x6C 0x26 0x71 0x2D 0x32 0x5A 0x55 0x5E 0x77 0x65 0x75

If anyone could run that through in python code it would be much appreciated

Comment: Python 2 or Python 3? And what exactly do you mean by "string of bytes"?

Comment: if i print it looks like b'....' Its the last 8 bytes received through a socket

Comment: "probably python 3"?  Funny.  Could you please do `import sys; sys.version` and post the answer? "probably" is useless and inoformative.

Comment: @user Strings changed fundamentally in Python 3. Any answer to this question is going to be specific to either 2 or 3. So unless you want to support both (which if so, you should have good reason) you really do need to decide which one you're using and let us know.

Comment: @S.Lott: "inoformative"?  +1 for inventing words to berate new users.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import struct
import hashlib

x = struct.pack('>II8B', 777007543, 114997259, 0x47, 0x30, 0x22, 0x2D, 0x5A, 0x3F, 0x47, 0x58)
hash = hashlib.md5(x).digest()

print [hex(ord(d)) for d in x]
(output) ['0x2e', '0x50', '0x31', '0xb7', '0x6', '0xda', '0xb8', '0xb', '0x47', '0x30', '0x22', '0x2d', '0x5a', '0x3f', '0x47', '0x58']

print [hex(ord(d)) for d in hash]
(output) ['0x30', '0x73', '0x74', '0x33', '0x52', '0x6c', '0x26', '0x71', '0x2d', '0x32', '0x5a', '0x55', '0x5e', '0x77', '0x65', '0x75']
```

Comment: +1: struct.pack.  Handles big-endian and small-ending so gracefully.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3828527/websockets-in-python3-1-handshake-problem - ha someone had linked to my blog on this site complaining my implementation doesn't work... well it does now anyway! Although it looks like http://stackoverflow.com/users/471795/kanaka has already done this.

Answer (score 2):

```
q = hex(777007543) + hex(114997259)[2:] + '4730222d5a3f4758'
```

just do this. here's why it works:

```
>>> num1, num2
(777007543, 114997259)
>>> hex(num1), hex(num2)
('0x2e5031b7', '0x6dab80b')
>>> hex(num1) + hex(num2) + '0x4730222d5a3f4758'
'0x2e5031b70x6dab80b0x4730222d5a3f4758'
>>> hex(num1) + hex(num2)[2:] + '4730222d5a3f4758'
'0x2e5031b76dab80b4730222d5a3f4758'
>>> int(_, 16)
3847554995347152223960862296285071192L
```

it's not difficult however to deal exactly with the representation you showed in your answer, if you want

edit:

here is what scott griffhits said. He's right ;)

> "
>
> Using hex only works here because the
>   numbers are large enough to need 8 hex
>   digits. We need to use a format, for
>   example `'{0:08x}{1:08x}'.format(num1,
>   num2)` will pad the hex with up to
>   eight zeros.
>
> "

Comment: Using `hex` only works here because the numbers are large enough to need 8 hex digits. For smaller numbers you'd need a `format` to get it to pad properly with zeros.

Comment: For example `'{0:08x}{1:08x}'.format(num1, num2)` will pad the hex with up to eight zeros.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you a list of all the values you want,

```
>>> [777007543 >> i & 0xff for i in xrange(24,0,-8)] + \
... [114997259 >> i & 0xff for i in xrange(24,0,-8)] + \
... map(ord, stringofbytes)
```

or even better (from the [other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594899/how-do-you-convert-a-decimal-number-into-a-list-of-bytes-in-python) you started),

```
>>> struct.unpack('>12B', \
... struct.pack('>L', 777007543) + struct.pack('>L', 114997259) + '.P1\xb7')
```

If you then want to make this a string to pass to your md5 hash,

```
>>> map(chr, _)
```

I am assuming that each byte of the string is supposed to represent a 1byte number.